# Unpredictable Games.RealTimeMultiplayer callbacks

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have no idea, where is the issue tracker for Google Play Games. It seems like an obvious bug to me. It probably cost me a lot of money and time, since I can't finish my game based on this RealTimeMultiplayer. Here is a simple situations description.

I have 3 devices, all have separate Google + account.
Let's name them **A**, **B** and **C**.

**SITUATION 1**

**A** invited **B** and **C**.

Later on **B** has left the game.

```
Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.leave(getApiClient(), this, room.getRoomId());
```

**A** get's only one callback called

- `onP2PConnected()`: **B** (seriously? Connected?!)

**C** gets several callbacks:

- `onP2PDisconnected()`: **B**
- `onPeerLeft()`: **B**
- `onPeersDisconnected()`: **A** (great, so now **A** lost connection aswell)
- `onPeersDisconnected()`: **B**

**SITUATION 2**

**A** invited **B** and **C**. This is pretty much the same as **Situation 1**, just **C** leaves instead of **B**.

Later on **C** has left the game.

**A** get's callbacks

- `onP2PDisconnected()`: **C**
- `onPeerLeft()`: **C**
- `onPeersDisconnected()`: **B**
- `onPeersDisconnected()`: **C**

**B** get's callbacks

- `onP2PDisconnected()`: **C**
- `onPeerLeft()`: **C**
- `onPeersDisconnected()`: **A**
- `onPeersDisconnected()`: **C**

**SITUATION 3**

**A** invited **B** and **C**.

Later on **A** has left the game.

**B** get's no callbacks called at all.

**C** get's `onP2PDisconnected(): **B**`

This doesn't make ANY sense.

Comment: I could not figure out how to handle disconnections as well